# Cardinality of Special Linear Group

Tags: group-theory

If cardinality of the field is $p^k$, where $p$ is a prime number, then order of $SL_n(F) = (\text{cardinality of } GL_n(F))/(p^k -1)$.
Where $p^k-1$ is the number of equivalence classes.
I know how this formula works. If we divide cardinality of $GL_n(F)$ by total number of equivalence classes in $GL_n(F)$, we will get cardinality of one equivalence class, where an equivalence class contains all the matrices of field having same determinant.

The problem is how do we get the total number of equivalence classes = $p^k -1$ ?

Answer (score 3):

With

$SL_n(F) = \{g \in GL_n(F) \mid \det(g) = 1 \}, \tag 1$

we have that

$g_1 SL_n(F) = g_2 SL_n(F) \tag 2$

if and only if

$\det g_1 = \det g_2, \tag 3$

since

$h \in g_1 SL_n(F) \Longleftrightarrow h = g_1 k, \tag 4$

for some $k \in SL_n(F)$; then

$\det h = \det(g_1 k) = \det(g_1) \det(k) = \det(g_1), \tag 5$

by virtue of the fact that

$\det(k) = 1; \tag 6$

the same argument applies to $g_2 SL_n(F)$; therefore the cosets of $SL_n(F)$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the non-zero elements of $F$, which are precisely $p^k - 1$ in number.  The desired results follows by a simple application of Lagrange's theorem.